# Does WIFI work with only range extender

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, home-networking

I've seen a lot of gizmos marketed as "wifi range extenders" recently and haven't bought a wireless router for a good 5-6 years.  I was wondering, since my home network is used to be:

```
[DSL Modem] <-Ethernet-> [WiFi Router] <-Wireless-> [Gizmos]
```

and now is:

```
[DSL Modem] <-Ethernet-> [Ubuntu Server] <-Wireless-> [WiFi Router] <-Wireless-> [Gizmos]
```

where previously the WiFi router was doing DHCP and now my own server is doing all that stuff, and then some.

---

If I've turned off DHCP and have no cords plugged in to a typical WiFi home networking router designed as a bridge between a broadband modem.  Can I downgrade the functionality in getting a new device (no built in routing, etc) to save some money, while upgrading the capability (having 5ghz would be a good start) and what class of devices would this be that I want?  Is it a Wireless Access Point or a WiFi Range Extender?

Does one have an IP address and the other function more like a hub, I'm guessing they always have some on-board configuration widget because I'd need to configure the password and ESSID, but I was a little worried that some of the gizmos out there might be dumb enough to just need to glean their information off a preexisting WiFi router, so I wanted to ask about them before making a purchase.

Comment: You need a wireless access point (WAP)

Comment: @red why?  what's the difference between a wireless access point and a range extender?

Comment: see answer for more info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **what's the difference between a wireless access point and a range extender?**

### WAP

A [wireless access point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_access_point) connects to Ethernet and provides all the WiFi services, such as broadcasting the SSID, providing authentication and so on.

### Extender

The purpose of a [wireless range-extender](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wi-Fi#Standard_devices) (AKA wireless repeater) is essentially akin to boosting the radio signal. It requires an existing WiFi network.

### Terminology

Marketing weasels are notorious for taking a popular and useful term and misusing it (creatively lying) in the expectation it will help sell stuff to people who don't know any better - thereby boosting marketroid bonuses - the net effect is to make human language useless. So take care.

---

> **what class of devices would this be that I want?**

A WAP.

> **Is it a Wireless Access Point or a WiFi Range Extender?**

The former.

> **Does one have an IP address**

Network infrastructure devices only need an IP-address if you are going to configure it remotely *in-band*. In ye olden days network kit had serial ports for out-of-band configuration and monitoring. Dumb stuff (e.g. basic hubs) don't need an IP-address.

> **and the other function more like a hub**

A WAP is like an Ethernet hub in that it provides the lower layers of networking below IP. Thereby providing a mechanism for delivering packets to multiple end-devices based on MAC address.